# Unused Bundle Resource, not found on disk, after deleting it?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to delete all the unused assets, to decrease the app size (icons, launch screens, etc), I started with the iOS project, but now I'm getting errors like this:

> Bundle Resource 'Icon-Small@3x.png' not found on disk (should be at
>   'D:\Work\MyProj\MyProj\MyProj\MyProj.iOS\Resources\Icon-Small@3x.png')

I deleted the specified file, but it's not used in the project, at least it's not visually used. Some of the missed files are the default Xamarin X icons.
I deleted the array items in `CFBundleIconFiles` key, which pointed to all the missing files, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Manually delete the reference from the .csproj file.  Then do a rebuild.  Doing this worked for me.

Note:  When I searched the solution for my image name, nothing was found.  However, after opening the project file(.csproj) for editing and then searching, the image name was found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know well about `xamarin`. But in Xcode, the images files are removed from Xcode better than from `Find` file utilities.

The project has a directory, `.xcodeproj`. And a file `project.pbxproj` will describe how many files will be compiled, and how many images resources in this project.

If a image file was deleted from file system, but it is still in this `project.pbxproj`. Then the compiler will argue this problem about it failed to find the image resource file.

So, deleting a image file in Xcode, will remove the entry from `project.pbxproj` and remove it from file system. 
In Xcode, it will mark red colors for those missed files, I think xamarin should has similar feature too.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know this info.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS , some  icons are required . Items marked with "Required" must be included.Refer the following image.

[image]

As we can seen ,`Icon-Small@3x.png` is required.It used for seetings on device (such as iPhoneX and iPhoneXs Max).Such as the icon in the following image.

[image]

So ,though you have  deleted the array items in `CFBundleIconFiles` key.You will still get the error .

Comment: I deleted old images that had been changed over the course of developing the application, and are replaced by new images. Is it just naming problem, do I need to rename the current images?

Comment: Not yet, I'm confused, there is two folders in the project:
MyProj.iOS\Assets.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset
and MyProj.iOS\Resources .. which one is being used the application and need the work?

Comment: MyProj.iOS\Assets.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset.It contains the icons

Comment: Hey,did you sovled the issue？

Comment: Not yet, have you noticed the path VS is complaining about? it's Resources not Assets.xcassets .. the error is thrown from the iOS project

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is chances are you deleted the source files, but Xamarin still keeps on referencing them.
So resolve this error go to each folder, Resources and Resources/Drawables on android and delete each image separately. This should fix your issue